# Codeigniter PHP Save Array Data and Getting back values for edit

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this array data on my form.i used a controller to display value list.if i want to store it to database,using value of 1,and when i want to edit the data,it shows the text on dropdown.for example :

```
$data['material'] = array(
                          '1'=> 'Plastic',
                          '2'=> 'Rubber',
                          '3'=> 'Metal',
                         );
<select>
    <?php foreach($material as $value)
          {
            echo '<option value=".$value['....']."'>'.$value['....'].'</option>
          }
</select>
```

any tips for doing this ? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `associated` array of `key/value` pairs.So try like below.

```
foreach($material as $key=>$value)
          {
            echo "<option value="'.$key.'">".$value."</option>";
          }
```

Comment: wait i'll try..i'll let you now when i've make the changes